# Python: How can I round each value in a two-dimensional Pandas dataframe to N decimal places while preserving the overall sum?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rounding

Goal: round each individual value in the two-dimensional (2D) dataframe to N decimal places while preserving the overall sum of the dataframe (to N decimal places). For example, if the overall table sum was 500.29239, then sum-safe rounding to 2 decimal places should result in an overall sum of 500.29. The `pandas.DataFrame.round` function rounds each individual value but does not necessarily preserve the overall sum. The `iteround.saferound()` function performs sum-safe rounding, but only on one-dimensional (1D) objects.

I have a solution (see my 'answer' below), but I wondered if anyone has a nicer (one-line) solution. My current solution involves converting the 2D dataframe into a 1D object, and then applying the iteround.saferound() function which seems to only work on 1D objects, and then converting it back into a 2D dataframe.

I have not come across full existing solutions to this question online, so I figured there might be value in posting the question and my current solution.

I'm new - sorry if I'm not doing this right! I am happy to edit my question/answer/both as needed.

Answer (score 1):

My (OP) own current solution that I am looking to improve upon / simplify:

```
import pandas as pd
import iteround  # For rounding values in a table without changing overall sum
import numpy as np
import itertools as it  # A number of iterator building blocks


#########################################
# Create example pandas dataframe table #
#########################################
def generate_example_pandas_df():
    """
    Generate pandas dataframe of 36 rows and 6 columns with random values.

    Returns
    -------
    example_data : DataFrame
        Pandas DataFrame containing 36 rows and 6 columns with random values.
    """
    np.random.seed(123)

    prefix = ["North", "East", "South", "West", "Middle", "Statistical"]
    suffix = ["port", "ville", "shire", "end", "don", "mouth"]

    nyear, ystart = 6, 2016

    area_names = ["".join(x) for x in it.product(prefix, suffix)]

    # Data is array with rows equal to length of area names list and columns
    # equal to value of nyear variable, filled with random numbers between 0 to 100.
    example_data = pd.DataFrame(
        np.random.uniform(0.00, 100.00, size=(len(area_names), nyear)),
        columns=[int(y + ystart) for y in range(nyear)],
        index=area_names,
    )

    return example_data


##################
# Apply rounding #
##################
def round_2d_pandas_dataframe(data, decimal_places=0, print_results=True):
    """
    Sum-safe round two-dimensional (2D) Pandas DataFrame to chosen decimal places (dp).
    This function rounds each value in a 2D Pandas DataFrame to the chosen number of
    dp while preserving the overall sum of DataFrame (it is 'sum-safe').
    For example, applying this function to a DataFrame that sums to 500.1919
    with decimal_places set to 1 will result in a DataFrame that sums to 500.2,
    whereas `pandas.DataFrame.round()` rounds individual values without
    regard for the overall sum of the DataFrame.

    Parameters
    ----------
    data : DataFrame
        The input Pandas DataFrame to apply the rounding to.
    decimal_places : int, optional
        Chosen number of decimal places to round to. The default is 0.
    print_results : bool, optional
        Whether to print a results summary to console. The default is True.
    Returns
    -------
    output_data : DataFrame
        The output Pandas DataFrame after rounding.
    """
    # Convert the 2D DataFrame into a 1D DataFrame for compatibility with .saferound()
    output_data = data.stack().to_frame().T

    output_data.iloc[0] = iteround.saferound(output_data.iloc[0], decimal_places)

    # Convert from 1D DataFrame back to 2D DataFrame
    output_data = output_data.T.unstack()

    # Drop the superfluous extra index header created by .unstack()
    output_data.columns = output_data.columns.droplevel()

    differences = data - output_data

    # Identify the greatest positive and negative individual value changes
    max_pos_change = round((differences.max(axis=1)).max(axis=0), decimal_places + 3)
    max_neg_change = round((differences.min(axis=1)).min(axis=0), decimal_places + 3)

    # Identify the before and after values for the top-left cell (to present as example)
    top_left_pre = data.iloc[0].iloc[0]
    top_left_post = output_data.iloc[0].iloc[0]

    overall_sum_change = round(
        data.sum().sum() - output_data.sum().sum(), decimal_places + 3
    )

    if print_results is True:
        print(f"Decimal places rounded to: {decimal_places}")
        print(f"Individual value changes : " f"{max_neg_change} to {max_pos_change}")
        print(f"Overall sum pre-rounding : {data.sum().sum()}")
        print(f"Overall sum post-rounding: {output_data.sum().sum()}")
        print(f"Overall table sum change : {overall_sum_change}")
        print(f"Example of top left value: {top_left_pre} became {top_left_post}")

    return output_data


input_df = generate_example_pandas_df()
output_df = round_2d_pandas_dataframe(
    data=input_df, decimal_places=1, print_results=True
)


"""
                 2016       2017       2018       2019       2020       2021
Northport   69.646919  28.613933  22.685145  55.131477  71.946897  42.310646
Decimal places rounded to: 1
Individual value changes : -0.0511 to 0.0485
Overall sum pre-rounding : 10918.659674395305
Overall sum post-rounding: 10918.7
Overall table sum change : -0.0403
Example of top left value: 69.64691855978616 became 69.6
"""
```

(I'm new - sorry if I'm not doing this right! I am happy to edit my question/answer/both as needed.)